# Find exact match with regular expression without preleading string in python

Tags: python, regex, match, python-re

I have a text file called my_file.txt that has the following content:

```
                                  R.A.O.S-VARIATION WITH WAVE PERIOD/FREQUENCY
                              VEL R.A.O.S-VARIATION WITH WAVE PERIOD/FREQUENCY
                              ACC R.A.O.S-VARIATION WITH WAVE PERIOD/FREQUENCY
                              SOME OTHER STRING
```

Now, I want to find the string `R.A.O.S-VARIATION WITH WAVE PERIOD/FREQUENCY` without any of the two other choises that have either `VEL` or `ACC` in it using a regular expression. There are white spaces before those strings.

How do I get the correct match using:

```
re.search(regex, line)
```

How should the regular expression look like that finds the desired string, without the two other options? I prefer to not specify all preleading white spaces in the string.

Comment: Find the start of each line, then 0+ whitespace character followed by exactly what you are looking for until the end of a line. Put this logic in a pattern. Sidenote: What do you want to do with the match? Do you need to know if the substring exists? Do you need to pull it from the text? Replace it in the text?

Comment: Hi Jeroen, could you share what you have tried so far? It is also unclear to me what your output should look like, may you share it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed-string match like this, you don't need a regular expression.

Use this instead:

```
if line.strip() == "R.A.O.S-VARIATION WITH WAVE PERIOD/FREQUENCY":
    # do stuff
```

If you really want to use a regular expression, use `re.fullmatch()` to match the whole line:

```
if re.fullmatch(r"\s*R\.A\.O\.S-VARIATION WITH WAVE PERIOD/FREQUENCY\s*", line):
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is remove the leading whitespace using the `.lstrip()` function and then search for the string.

```
re.search(regex, line.lstrip())
```

Answer (score -1):

`re.findall(r'R.A.O.S-VARIATION WITH WAVE PERIOD/FREQUENCY', line)`

Comment: This will also match when there is preceding text, so this does not answer the question.